# Custom labels coming in text payload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, winston, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to use google-cloud/logging-winston Cloud Function.

I want to use **prefix** & **labels** but when I configure them based on the google-cloud/logging-winston documentation nothing works.

As it can be seen in the pic. Label is added to the textpayload and prefix is not used at all.

Any idea whats wrong and how to fix this...

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {

  const winston = require('winston');

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library for Winston
  const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

  const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston({ 
    serviceContext: {
      service: 'winston-test',
      version: '1'
    },
    prefix: 'DataInflow' 
  });

  // Create a Winston logger that streams to Stackdriver Logging
  // Logs will be written to: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/winston_log"
  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console(),
      // Add Stackdriver Logging
      loggingWinston,
    ],
  });

  // Writes some log entries
  //logger.debug('Testing labels', { labels: { module: 'Test Winston Logging' }});
  logger.error('Testing labels', { custom_metadata: 'yes', labels: { module: 'Test Winston Logging' }});

  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

[image]

**Edit#1:** If I specify the keyFilename=path-to-sa-json-file then it works.

```
  const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston({ 
    serviceContext: {
      service: 'winston-test',
      version: '1'
    },
    prefix: 'DataInflow',
    keyFilename=path-to-sa-json-file.json
  });
```

But this is strange. Cloud Function & logging-winston library should use Application Default Credentials (ADC).

So if the service account I use with my CF has stackdriver write access then it should be fine.

Is my understanding wrong? Anyone having other insights...

**Edit#2:** Seems to be an issue with Cloud Functions on Nodejs 10. Its working quite fine with Nodejs 8 without specifying the keyFilename... quite strange...

Comment: It could be because of Nodejs10 runtime, because it's in [beta](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-10-runtime).  But first I want to know how are you using "prefix" parameter? I am asking because in the [LoggingWinston](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/logging-winston/0.7.x/LoggingWinston) library there is no such parameter.

Comment: @nibrass-haider check the latest documentation https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/logging-winston/latest/index.html

Comment: Look into this Official Documentation, [Finding credentials automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application). Did you follow these steps? In case yes, let me know.

Comment: @nibrass-haider, I think I found the issue. I need to find the logs under label winston-logs and not under the default label... Also if u r throwing error they should also show up in Error Reporting...

Comment: Do you solve the issue? In case yes, you can post an answer for other community members. Let me know if you were able to solve the issue.

Comment: @NibrassHaider I have posted my answer... Let me know what is ur issue... may be I can help.

Comment: Thank you, I only asked in case you didn't solve the issue and to investigate further to help you.

Comment: @NibrassHaider thanks for ur time... There r few things regarding GCP which I find not that well documented and thus they need lot more googling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to sort out the issue. All winston logs are stored in stackdriver under custom label so this was the issue in my case.

With the below code I was able to log the error to stackdriver and also to error reporting.

In error reporting I could find my errors under `service -> winston-test` and in stackdriver under `All logs -> winston_log`

```
 /**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {

  const winston = require('winston');

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library for Winston
  const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

  const metadata = {
    resource: {
      type: 'global',
      serviceContext: {
        service: 'winston-test',
        version: '1'
      },
      prefix: 'DataInflow' 
    }
  };


  const resource = {
    // This example targets the "global" resource for simplicity
    type: 'global',
  };


  const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston({ resource: resource });

  // Create a Winston logger that streams to Stackdriver Logging
  // Logs will be written to: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/winston_log"
  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console(),
      // Add Stackdriver Logging
      loggingWinston,
    ],
  });

  // Writes some log entries
  //logger.debug('Testing labels', { labels: { module: 'Test Winston Logging' }});
  logger.error(Error('Testing labels'));

  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```